# How to resolve this name issue having white space while installing the android Studio.?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

SDK location should not contain whitespace, as this can cause problems with the NDK tools.

[image] It says that the path name should not contain any white spaces. But i cant rename it.

[image] There is no any rename option for that folder when right clicked.

When i change the folder to which there is not any space, it says that "Target Folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK Installation." 
[image]

Comment: Hi Charan. Can you please include the images of the IDE warnings in your post [Upload them to StackOverflow]. This will help to ensure the post remains useful should those links stop working in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Elletlar I am a newbie to Stackoverflow and when added image it shows as a link apart from showing in the post. By googling I came to know that my reputation score should be more than 10 to add images in the post..

Comment: Okay. Good to know thank you. I've attached the images to your post.

Comment: I up-voted your question. You now have enough reputation. Please accept one of the answers below if they helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A good candidate for your Android SDK parent is the [ProgramData](https://www.howtogeek.com/278562/what-is-the-programdata-folder-in-windows/) folder.

Answer (score 0):

Move the SDK out of the `C:\Users\CHARAN KUMAR` folder and into a folder in the `C:\` drive that doesn't have any whitespace (perhaps `C:\Android\SDK\` or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

Using an administrator account on Windows create either a symbolic link or a junction to the user's directory.

Symbolic link:  `mklink /d CHARANKUMAR "CHARAN_KUMAR`

Junction:  `mklink /j CHARANKUMAR "CHARAN_KUMAR`

Now you can use the C:\CHARANKUMAR\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk directory.